# Which tape drives were the last to offer backward compatibility with QIC-150 Tape Cartridges?

Tags: storage, scsi, magnetic-tape

I currently have some QIC-150 tape cartridges. These are the Imation DC6250 250 MB tapes. I understand that this came out in the late 1990's. I'd like to read these using a tape drive but want to find the last and newest model that could still read them. For example, I read somewhere that the SLR1 line was equivalent to the QIC-150?

I am wondering if anyone would know if there are any resources detailing conversion and backwards compatibility with these tapes.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, [SLR1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Linear_Recording) is what Tandberg called [QIC-150](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarter-inch_cartridge#3M_Data_Cartridge_(DC)). They may as well have been one of the last manufacturers of QIC-150 compatible drives. Next, QIC-150 was defined (and first offered) in 1984. THe last standard document is dated [June 1991](https://www.qic.org/html/qicstan.html).

Further, there is no real sense in looking for a 'latest' drive, as that may be an IBM device with a mainframe interface. I think I'm safe to assume that you're rather would like to look for any drive adhering to the standard with an interface supported by whatever computer can handle.